# Error merging pcap dump files from tcpdump

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I have a number of capture files that I am trying to merge. The merge files are from linux servers (both Ubuntu and Centos), a Macbook Pro and from a Windows machine.  They all play nice with the exception of the mac dump.

But when I try to merge the files from the mac I get this error:

> "mergecap: Record 222 of "scenario_4_mbp.pcap" has an interface ID which does not match any IDB in its file."

I looked at the specific packet and it is a Dropbox LAN sync Discovery Protocol. For my purposes I don't even care about it, and I would just as soon like to filter it out but I cannot seem to get the filter correct.

I tried to filter with:

```
ip.proto != db-lsp-disc 
ip.proto not db-lsp-disc
```

but I get an error and nothing is filtered.

Assuming I am able to apply a display filter how do I save the file sans the dropbox packets?  And ultimately, will this solve my merge issue?

Comment: Are these pcap files or pcapng files?  Pcap files don't have interface IDs or I(nterface) D(escription) B(locks), only pcapng files do, so either 1) "scenario_4_mbp.pcap" is actually a pcapng file or 2) mergecap is incorrectly reporting the problem.  What happens if you try to read "scenario_4_mbp.pcap" with Wireshark?

Comment: I can read and open the file just fine with Wireshark, but I cannot merge it with the other files from the scenario.   All the files were captured using tcpdump with the same settings.  The only thing different is that this file is being captured on a Mac and all the others are from Linux servers (CentOS 6.5)

Answer (score 0):

> I can read and open the file just fine with Wireshark, but I cannot merge it with the other files from the scenario.

Then this is probably a bug in mergecap.  Please file a bug on [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org/), and, if possible, attach to the bug capture files that demonstrate the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and the offending file in my case was also created with `tcpdump` on a MacOS machine.

I was able to solve the problem by opening the offending file in Wireshark, which has no problem with it, then doing a "Save As" into a new .pcapng file, then running `mergecap` again replacing the offending file with the newly created copy.

Saving as a regular .pcap file seemed to work, too, but there are comments in the file (interface names, at least) that regular .pcap strips out.